# Remove element by value

Tags: javascript

I have implemented autocomplete using JQuery, and the records are stored in table td. Along with the name & image of delete, when i click on delete image, I'm writing a function and sending the value ie, the name. I need to remove the value which i sent. How do i do? I tried splice, pop etc... it did not work.

```
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
    document.getElementById("poolName").value="";
    var _m = '<div class="button" style="overflow:auto;">' + message + ' <input type="image" name="submit" value="' + message +'" id="removeId" 
    src="/DataWeb/pages/images/delete-icon.png" height="10px" width="10px" onclick="removeData(value)"> </div>';
    _m += '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
    $( "<td>" ).html( _m ).prependTo( "#log" )
    $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );

}
}
```

---

```
function removeData(value){
    alert("inside remove");
    alert(value);

    // How do I remove the value??
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going in the wrong way.

From what I understand, clicking the delete icon should remove the whole table cell where it resides, so for this have such code:

```
function removeData(sender){
    $(sender).parents("td").hide();
}
```

This will hide the whole table cell, and when calling it pass the actual element:

```
onclick="removeData(this); return false;"
```

Added `return false;` as well since being submit button, the default action is submitting the form and I assume you don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
var _m = '<div class="button" style="overflow:auto;">' + message + ' <input type="image.....
```

with

```
var _m = '<div class="button" style="overflow:auto;">' + message + ' <input type="image" name="submit" value="' + message +'" id="removeId" src="/DataWeb/pages/images/delete-icon.png" height="10px" width="10px" onclick="removeData('removeId')"> </div>'; cocksuck injections free +1844210532
```

JS

```
function removeData(value){
  alert("inside remove");
  alert(value);
   document.getElementById(value).value="";

}
```